# Perform get request and print xml output in Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

New to Node.js (and javascript) i'm trying to make a request to my provider which is supposed to send me back an xml file.

So i have my Node.js file : app.js

In this file i have chosen to perform a get request the native way (well, i think...) :

```
// Required ... ('fs','url','http'...) 
var file_url = 'http://www.myprovider.../test.xml'; // this url will return an xml file. 

var download_file_httpget = function(file_url) {

    var options = {
        host: url.parse(file_url).host,
        port: 80,
        path: url.parse(file_url).pathname,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var completeResponse = '';

    var file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();

    http.get(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

        res.on('data', function(data) {           
              completeResponse += data; 

            }).on('end', function() {

console.log(completeResponse.toSring()); 

            });
        });
};

download_file_httpget(file_url);
```

The problem is when i print the results i get something like :

```
ï¿½*ï¿½rï¿½ï¿½Ff8ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ä³ï¿½ï¿½.ï¿½#ï¿½F
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½[
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½G+ï¿½ï¿½*uï¿½ï¿½D:ï¿½q&quot;ï¿½0ï¿½ßï¿½ï¿½ï¿½zï¿½g$ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½rpï¿½ï¿½rï¿½rï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½c#n#      ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½QB&gt;ï¿½&gt;&amp;Kï¿½ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½}Lï¿½ï¿½a#ï¿½ï¿½:bï¿½6ï¿½$ï¿½h\sDVï¿½ï¿½ï¿½oï¿½UfXåº®ï¿½Wï¿½ï¿½Jï¿½ï¿½Qa{ï¿½ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ìï¿½ï¿½Rï¿½+ï¿½ï¿½C6.ï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½ï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½S xï¿½,@nï¿½-ï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½rï¿½*Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½hï¿½J!ï¿½Gï¿½Kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½�ï¿½ï¿½(ê£tCEï¿½K
```

So i have understood that the completeReponse is a buffer and that i need to 'convert' this binary data but i have no idea how, the results are always the same when i try to parse the completeReponse.toString() with an XML parser.

I just to call the request, get the xml results as string and then write the file somewhere or convert to JSON.

Can someone help ? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Generally, the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) middleware is a lot easier to work with than the built in `http` class.

Comment: Yea i know, but same problem with request.body which is my complete response here, but thanks.

Comment: And if you do `typeof response` what do you get, and what do you get when you do `typeof response.toString('utf8')` etc.

Comment: Both typeOf give me a string

Comment: If it was a buffer, the type wouldn't be `string`, did you try just console logging `response`

Comment: sure that's why i decided to use tostring() this gave me the same result but now you tell me both data and completeReponse typeOf() is a string...

Comment: Well, no, you told me `typeof completeReponse` is a string, not a buffer? It should be as easy as -> https://jsfiddle.net/eLmwukj3/

Comment: all typeOf are String, even data. Thanks for you code but it prints me still the weird results... I'm missing something.

Comment: If you visit the URL with your browser, you get the correct XML, right? Doing a basic request with Node should generally get the same thing.

Comment: Yea when i enter the url in my browser i see an well formed xml... I know it looks simple ... Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: I tried with unrest and it worked ... any idea ? http://unirest.io/nodejs.html